# Proper syntactic reference for Python class attributes

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, attributes

Having known the difference between class and instance attributes in Python, which of these two is the proper way to reference a class attribute?

```
import requests


class SomePage:
    
    PAGE_URL = 'www.someurl.com'

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        # Option A
        self.request_a = requests.get(self.PAGE_URL)
        # Option B
        self.request_b = requests.get(SomePage.PAGE_URL)
```

The result would be the same for any option. Is there any of them preferable?

Comment: `request` is not defined -- should be `requests`. But actually, for the sake of example, you might as well just use `print`, like `print(self.PAGE_URL); print(SomePage.PAGE_URL)`. For reference see [mre].

Comment: Yea sorry I did the example on the fly without any editor other than Stack Overflow. Thanks for the advice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are not the same, so what you use depends on what you intend. This becomes clear if we consider the following example:

```
class Foo:
    bar = 42
    def method1(self):
        return self.bar
    def method2(self):
        return Foo.bar

class Baz(Foo):
    bar = 99

baz = Baz()
```

In the repl:

```
>>> baz.method1()
99
>>> baz.method2()
42
```

So, `self.PAGE_URL` will *check the instance namespace, then the class namespace, then all the namespaces in the classes method resolution order*.

On the other hand `Foo.bar` will *check `Foo`'s namespace, then all namespaces in Foo's method resolution order*.

Comment: I'd also add `type(self).bar` to check the class namespace then MRO.